# EF Core 7.0.5 model and its object property to same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relational-database, object-property, ef-model-builder

I have a model in which 3 classes (part of the complete model)

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public City? City { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }//OrderId
    public Customer? Customer { get; set; }       
    //more properties in Customer structure
}
```

And the following tables:

```
tbl_customers
---------------------------------------------------------------------
id | customer_id | customer_first_name | customer_last_name | city_id

tbl_city
-----------------------------------------------------------
city| city_desc| dist
```

All the data from `Order` and `Customer` should be poured into table `tbl_customers`.

In `Customer` there is `City` property which mapped to `foreign key` to `tbl_city`

So, I build a `Context` ([Instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting#configurations))

```
public class EntityContext: DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer("myConnectionString");

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<City>(c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("tbl_city")
                 .HasKey(c => c.Id);

                c.Property(c => c.Id)
                 .HasColumnName("city");

                c.Property(c => c.Name)
                 .HasColumnName("city_desc");

                c.Property(c => c.District)
                 .HasColumnName("dist");
          });            

          modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(c =>
          {
                c.ToTable("tbl_customers")
                 .HasKey(c=>c.Id);
                c.Property(c=>c.Id).HasColumnName("id");
                
                c.HasOne(e => e.Customer)
                           .WithOne()
                           .HasForeignKey("customer_id");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(c =>
            {
                 c.ToTable("tbl_customers");                
                c.Property(c => c.Id)
                .HasColumnName("customer_id");
                c.Property(c => c.FirstName)
                .HasColumnName("customer_first_name");
                c.Property(c => c.LastName)
                .HasColumnName("customer_last_name");
            });
        }
}
```

But I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'tbl_customers' for entity type 'Order' since it is being used for entity type 'Customer' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'Order' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'tbl_customers'.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IReadOnlyList`1 mappedTypes, StoreObjectIdentifier& storeObject, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
> at  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.ValidateSharedTableCompatibility(IReadOnlyList`1 mappedTypes, StoreObjectIdentifier& storeObject, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)

[There is similar question without solution to the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76173391/efcore-owned-model-has-object-property-mapped-to-foreignkey) with different context

Comment: What do you mean by "All the data from Order and Customer should be poured into table tbl_customers." Is a Customer only allowed to have one Order? I would suggest a Customer to have a List<Order> Orders. And to create a table Orders.

Comment: @jeb: As you can see in the table structure, the `Order` and the`Customer` in the same table - that what I meant in that sentance.
You should see `Customer` as expansion of `Order` and not as an independent entity, and I can't change the `model` just the `context`

Comment: Ah i see. But it is still not clear to me. For example: How should that work when a Customer has an Id and an Order has an Id. ? Where in the table is the OrderId shown? Ah, i guess its the Id property of the table.

Comment: @jeb, The `Id` of the `Customer` and the `Id` of `Order` mapped to different columns but only the `Order` `Id` is `primaryKey`(yes, the `id` column) as you can see in the `Context`

Comment: if you cannot change the existing models i would suggest creating a new model or a new dbset. And Map to that new model. I don't think (or at least i don't know how) you can map this only by the changing the ef core configuration.